# ASP.NET App Initialization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In regular MVC app, the Application_Start method (and others) is not virtual. Therefore, this method must be called through reflection, and there are som naming convention. But why did they choose it like so? Instead, I would rather look at the base class' virtual methods and choose one to override. Now I have to go to docs. Why don't declare even handling methods in the base class.

P.S. In the new ASP.NET Core the Startup class even has no base class.

Comment: Why did they do it like that? Likely because ASP.NET inherited this approach from classic ASP. But any answers outside of the original development team (including this comment) will be speculative at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In former applications, the "entry" is not called from managed .NET code, naming convention is the most direct way, imagine `static void Main`.

For ASP.NET core applications, the entry is `Main` method, where you can specify a startup class using `.UseStartup` method of `IWebHostBuilder` extension. There is no constraint of [`IStartup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.istartup) is because its signature can be changed, for example:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IEmailService emailService)
```

The arguments are resolved by `IServiceProvider`, registered in `ConfigureServices` method.